# Sqlite3 Vue.js & Express.js - Error

Tags: express, sqlite, vue.js, web-development-server

I am trying to install sqlite3 for a project using vue.js and express.js.

I don't know why, I am getting this error.

```
    $ npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=$(0.27.0)
bash: 0.27.0: command not found
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=$("0.27.0")

> sqlite3@3.1.13 install C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build


C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )
node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Empty target version is not supported if node-webkit is the target.
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at get_node_webkit_abi (C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:48:15)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at get_runtime_abi (C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:79:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate (C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:292:19)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at handle_gyp_opts (C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\handle_gyp_opts.js:54:27)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at configure (C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\configure.js:11:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\build.js:35:13
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:85:9)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:135:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:224:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Cosmin\\Desktop\\304CEM   Web API\\304CEM---Project\\server\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\304CEM   Web API\304CEM---Project\server\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cosmin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-11T01_56_43_514Z-debug.log
```

Any ideas on how to solve it  ? I have been trying to look on different other sources but with no luck.

Comment: There's an error message that states `Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help`.  Did you update node-pre-gyp?

Comment: Yes, I did, just installed the latest version. Same error. :(